# The apparently mismatched declension in the expression "über alle Maßen"

Tags: declension

> Sie ist **über alle Maßen** großzügig.

In this idiomatic expression, I'm not sure why the ***Plural Dative*** form "Maßen" is coupled with the ***Plural Accusative*** form "alle" instead of the ***Plural Dative*** form "allen".

I would be tempted to say instead:

> Sie ist **über allen Maßen** großzügig.

Comment: +1 for this very interesting observation

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Hi. Practially speaking, do native German speakers (as a child) learn this expression as a **set, fixed** phrase without dwelling too much on this apparent mismatch?

Comment: Yes, I learned it as a fixed phrase without ever questioning its grammar. And I gues this will be the case for most german native speakers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, *über* demands an accusative here, and that's why "alle" is correct here. ("über alle Maßen" means "über alle Maßen hinaus", so you have to ask "über wen?" and not "über wem?", *über* indicates a direction in this case).

But of course this does not solve your problem, since the mismatch seems to persist. The solution is that "Maßen" is actually *not* dative case here, but accusative as well.
But how can this be? The standard plural declension of "das Maß" would be

> Nominative plural: die Maße
>
> Genitive plural: der Maße
>
> Dative plural: den Maßen
>
> Akkusative plural: die Maße

But in the idiomatic expression *über alle Maßen*, "Maßen" is not the plural of the present-day German word *das Maß*, but of an elder variant *die Maß*, which has nearly completely vanished in Modern German from the 18th century on. Etymology of *das Maß* shows that it is a blending of Middle High German *māʒe* (feminine) and Middle High German *meʒ* (neuter). *Die Maß* has survived in Upper German *[die Maß](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ma%C3%9F#2)* and in present-day German *dermaßen*, *gewissermaßen* and *einigermaßen* (see [Pfeifer](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ma%C3%9F) for more detailed information) and - as I would conclude - in the idiomatic expression "über alle Maßen".

I have no *proof* for my hypothesis, that "über alle Maßen" is indeed a relict of the feminine variant *die Maß*, but it would explain the grammar of the idiomatic expression.

Comment: Note that the word *die Maß* hasn't actually vanished. In Bavaria it is still alive as a measure of beer. It used to be defined regionally (generally a bit more than what is now a litre), but in modern parlance it precisely 1 litre. The word comes up at least once a year on German national news when the Oktoberfest beer price is reported. - I suspect there might have be a sort of pun going on originally. You can think of the idiom as starting as a length-based metaphor and the final *n* turning it into an alcohol-based one.

Comment: @HansAdler "Note that the word die Maß hasn't actually vanished. In Bavaria it is still alive as a measure of beer." My answer does reflect this: "*Die Maß* has survived in Upper German*

Comment: Yes, but it's not just Upper German. While it's obviously much more common in (Austria and) Bavaria than elsewhere, it's also a word of Standard German describing something that one might refer to as a regional dish. I just feel that saying the word "almost completely vanished" is a bit too strong under the circumstances.

Comment: @HansAdler Well, I would say that *die Maß* understood in other parts of Germany as "1 liter of beer", but not actively used. But you are correct that it still exists. I admit, that it is hard to judge, whether it is *nearly* completely vanished or not.

Comment: @HansAdler Note that Duden considers *die Maße* (that's what we're talking about here) and *die Maß*  as two different words.

Answer (score 1):

**Vocabulary**

The word *die Maße* is **not** the same thing as *das Maß* or *die Maß* (the beer), it is actually, according to [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Masze), a different (archaic) word (*die Maße*, fem), and its plural is *die Maßen*. A proper English translation would be *standard* or *measure*. *die Maße* is so archaic that it is not used anymore in German except in this (and some others, like: *in Maßen*) idiomatic expression.

**Grammar**

Movement in German can be ruling two cases - dative and accusative:

1. *Static movement* within a restricted area or within certain limits rules the dative - *Ich fahre in der Stadt* - Moving about within a defined area.
2. *Dynamic movement* towards something is expressed using the accusative - *Ich fahre in die Stadt*. Expresses "were not there yet, but move towards it"

> Das Flugzeug fliegt über alle  Wolken

The plane is is on its way to the area above the clouds (accusative).

> Das Flugzeug fliegt über allen Wolken

The plane is constantly flying above the clouds (dative).

*Über alle Maßen* is accusative and does thus express a movement from *at or below standards* to *above all standards*.

Comment: "Über alle Maßen is accusative and does thus express a movement from below standards to above all standards." I think, that's wrong. *Das Essen war über alle Maßen gut* does not imply that it has been bad before. The "direction" which demans accusative case here is more of a conceptual manner - rather like in "to exceed all standards" than in "move from below all standards above all standards"

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach agree partially - "...über alle Maßen gut" does, however, also not say it has been **good** before - It just doesn't imply anything where we're coming from.